# Vbscript passing a variable from access database to email

Tags: database, asp-classic, vbscript

Why do I have to URLEncode a string with spaces from a database to pass to email (MAILTO subject) when if you create the mailto string manually you don't have to.
Eg: `<a href="mailo:contacts@fred.com?subject=Hello Fred this is Harry">example</A>`
works fine but if I get the subject from a database it only passes the first word "Hello" and trims the rest unless I use Server.URLEncode(stringfromdatabase). this inserts a + inplace of the spaces.

Is there a method that allows me to pass a string with spaces from a database to an email client that doesn't need to modify the string (adding + or %20)?

Comment: Seems like the issue is with your code.  Which you've not included, so it's hard to suggest anything...

Comment: I agree, it looks like the issue is with the piece of code that handles the extraction / passing the variable on, rather than this. The variable that you use as "Subject" does not get the entire string. Can you give us some more snippets of code?

Comment: In short, you need to figure out where exactly the "trip" happens.

Comment: the variable is ok, displays full string on mouseover but when its selected and clicked - opening a new email in client - only the first word is inserted into the subject line unless I replace all the spaces using urlencode.

Comment: Are you wrapping the href in quotes when populating from the database?

Comment: tried that unsuccessfully.

Response.Write "<a href='mailto:enquiries@mywebsite.com?subject=" & enquiry_subject & "'>Enquire</a>"

There is all kinds on data going into the subject line, including & and #, im experimenting with string clean routines currently.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a replace function to swap the spaces with `%20`. In your example the variable would be

```
replace(stringfromdatabase," ", "%20")
```

This worked for me using `VBScript` in the `ASP` page I was struggling with.

Comment: solved it thank you, used

| Function strClean (strtoclean)
  Dim objRegExp, outputStr
  Set objRegExp = New Regexp
  
  objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
  objRegExp.Global = True
  objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9\s*,]).)+"
  
  outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")
  
  objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
  outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "")
  
  strClean = outputStr
 End Function

Answer (score 0):

all sorted thank you used the following

Function CleanString(strData)
     'Replace invalid strings.
     strData = Replace(strData, "'",   "")
     strData = Replace(strData, "#",   "")
     strData = Replace(strData, "&",   "and")
     CleanString = Trim(strData)
  End Function

```
Function strClean (strtoclean)
    Dim objRegExp, outputStr
    Set objRegExp = New Regexp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9\s*,]).)+"

    outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")

    objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
    outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "")

    strClean = outputStr
End Function
```